# Stimuli changes with every frame being displayed.

Tags: psychopy

I have a bit of code (displayed below) that is supposed to display the stimulus for 10 frames. We need pretty exact display times, so using number of frames is a must instead of `core.wait(xx)` as the display time won't be as precise.

Instead of drawing the stimuli, and leaving it for another 9 frames - the stimuli is re-drawn for every frame.

```
# Import what is needed
import numpy as np
from psychopy import visual, event, core, logging
from math import sin, cos
import random, math

win = visual.Window(size=(1366, 768), fullscr=True, screen=0, allowGUI=False, allowStencil=False,
    monitor='testMonitor', color=[0,0,0], colorSpace='rgb',
    blendMode='avg', useFBO=True,
    units='deg')

### Definitions of libraries
'''Parameters :
    numpy       - python package of numerical computations
    visual      - where all visual stimulus live
    event       - code to deal with mouse + keyboard input
    core        - general function for timing & closing the program
    logging     - provides function for logging error and other messages to one file
    random      - options for creating arrays of random numbers
    sin & cos   - for geometry and trigonometry
    math        - mathematical operations  '''

# this is supposed to record all frames
win.setRecordFrameIntervals(True)
win._refreshThreshold=1/65.0+0.004 #i've got 65Hz monitor and want to allow 4ms tolerance
#set the log module to report warnings to the std output window (default is errors only)
logging.console.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

nIntervals=5

# Create space variables and a window
lineSpaceX = 0.55
lineSpaceY = 0.55

patch_orientation = 45 # zero is vertical, going anti-clockwise
surround_orientation = 90

#Jitter values
g_posJitter = 0.05 #gaussian positional jitter
r_posJitter = 0.05 #random positional jitter

g_oriJitter = 5 #gaussian orientation jitter
r_oriJitter = 5 #random orientation jitter

#create a 1-Dimentional array
line = np.array(range(38)) #with values from (0-37) #possibly not needed 01/04/16 DK

#Region where the rectangular patch would appear
#x_rand=random.randint(1,22) #random.randint(Return random integers from low (inclusive) to high (exclusive).
#y_rand=random.randint(1,25)


x_rand=random.randint(6,13) #random.randint(Return random integers from low (inclusive) to high (inclusive).
y_rand=random.randint(6,16)

#rectangular patch dimensions
width=15
height=12

message = visual.TextStim(win,pos=(0.0,-12.0),text='...Press SPACE to continue...')
fixation = visual.TextStim(win, pos=(0.0,0.0), text='X')

# Initialize clock to record response time
rt_clock = core.Clock()


#Nested loop to draw anti-aliased lines on grid
#create a function for this
def myStim():
    for x in xrange(1,33): #32x32 grid. When x is 33 will not execute loop - will stop
        for y in xrange(1,33): #When y is 33 will not execute loop - will stop
            ##Define x & y value (Gaussian distribution-positional jitter)
            x_pos = (x-32/2-1/2 )*lineSpaceX + random.gauss(0,g_posJitter) #random.gauss(mean,s.d); -1/2 is to center even-numbered stimuli; 32x32 grid
            y_pos = (y-32/2-1/2 )*lineSpaceY + random.gauss(0,g_posJitter)

            if (x >= x_rand and x < x_rand+width) and (y >= y_rand and y < y_rand+height): # note only "=" on one side
                Line_Orientation = random.gauss(patch_orientation,g_oriJitter) #random.gauss(mean,s.d) - Gaussian func.
            else:
                Line_Orientation = random.gauss(surround_orientation,g_oriJitter) #random.gauss(mean,s.d) - Gaussian func.
                #Line_Orientation = random.gauss(Line_Orientation,g_oriJitter) #random.gauss(mean,s.d) - Gaussian func.
                #stimOri = random.uniform(xOri - r_oriJitter, xOri + r_oriJitter) #random.uniform(A,B) - Uniform func.
            visual.Line(win, units = "deg", start=(0,0), end=(0.0,0.35), pos=(x_pos,y_pos), ori=Line_Orientation, autoLog=False).draw() #Gaussian func.



for frameN in range (10):
    myStim()
    win.flip()

print x_rand, y_rand 
print keys, rt  #display response and reaction time on screen output window
```

I have tried to use the following code to keep it displayed (by not clearing the buffer). But it just draws over it several times.

```
for frameN in range(10):
    myStim()
    win.flip(clearBuffer=False)
```

I realize that the problem could be because I have `.draw()` in the function that I have defined `def myStim():`. However, if I don't include the `.draw()` within the function - I won't be able to display the stimuli.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the problem you are facing is that you have to re-draw the stimulus on every flip, but your current drawing function also recreates the entire (random) stimulus, so:

- the stimulus changes on each draw between flips, although you need it to stay constant, and
- you get a (on some systems quite massive) performance penalty by re-creating the entire stimulus over and over again.

What you want instead is: create the stimulus once, in its entirety, before presentation; and then have this pre-generated stimulus drawn on every flip.

Since your stimulus consists of a fairly large number of visual elements, I would suggest using a class to store the stimulus *in one place*.

Essentially, you would replace your `myStim()` function with this class (note that I stripped out most comments, re-aligned the code a bit, and simplified the `if` statement):

```
class MyStim(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lines = []

        for x in xrange(1, 33):
            for y in xrange(1, 33):
                x_pos = ((x - 32 / 2 - 1 / 2) * lineSpaceX +
                         random.gauss(0,  g_posJitter))
                y_pos = ((y - 32 / 2 - 1 / 2) * lineSpaceY +
                         random.gauss(0, g_posJitter))

                if ((x_rand <= x < x_rand + width) and
                        (y_rand <= y < y_rand + height)):
                    Line_Orientation = random.gauss(patch_orientation,
                                                    g_oriJitter)
                else:
                    Line_Orientation = random.gauss(surround_orientation,
                                                    g_oriJitter)

                current_line = visual.Line(
                    win, units="deg", start=(0, 0), end=(0.0, 0.35),
                    pos=(x_pos, y_pos), ori=Line_Orientation,
                    autoLog=False
                )

                self.lines.append(current_line)

    def draw(self):
        [line.draw() for line in self.lines]
```

What this code does on instantiation is in principle identical to your `myStim()` function: it creates a set of (random) lines. But instead of drawing them onto the screen right away, they are all collected in the list `self.lines`, and will remain there until we actually need them.

The `draw()` method traverses through this list, element by element (that is, line by line), and calls every line's `draw()` method. Note that the stimuli do not have to be re-created every time we want to draw the whole set, but instead we just draw the already pre-created lines!

To get this working in practice, you first need to instantiate the `MyStim` class:

```
myStim = MyStim()
```

Then, whenever you want to present the stimulus, all you have to do is

```
myStim.draw()
win.flip()
```

Here is the entire, modified code that should get you started:

```
import numpy as np
from psychopy import visual, event, core, logging
from math import sin, cos
import random, math

win = visual.Window(size=(1366, 768), fullscr=True, screen=0, allowGUI=False, allowStencil=False,
    monitor='testMonitor', color=[0,0,0], colorSpace='rgb',
    blendMode='avg', useFBO=True,
    units='deg')

# this is supposed to record all frames
win.setRecordFrameIntervals(True)
win._refreshThreshold=1/65.0+0.004 #i've got 65Hz monitor and want to allow 4ms tolerance
#set the log module to report warnings to the std output window (default is errors only)
logging.console.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

nIntervals=5

# Create space variables and a window
lineSpaceX = 0.55
lineSpaceY = 0.55

patch_orientation = 45 # zero is vertical, going anti-clockwise
surround_orientation = 90

#Jitter values
g_posJitter = 0.05 #gaussian positional jitter
r_posJitter = 0.05 #random positional jitter

g_oriJitter = 5 #gaussian orientation jitter
r_oriJitter = 5 #random orientation jitter

x_rand=random.randint(6,13) #random.randint(Return random integers from low (inclusive) to high (inclusive).
y_rand=random.randint(6,16)

#rectangular patch dimensions
width=15
height=12

message = visual.TextStim(win,pos=(0.0,-12.0),text='...Press SPACE to continue...')
fixation = visual.TextStim(win, pos=(0.0,0.0), text='X')

# Initialize clock to record response time
rt_clock = core.Clock()


class MyStim(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lines = []

        for x in xrange(1, 33):
            for y in xrange(1, 33):
                x_pos = ((x - 32 / 2 - 1 / 2) * lineSpaceX +
                         random.gauss(0,  g_posJitter))
                y_pos = ((y - 32 / 2 - 1 / 2) * lineSpaceY +
                         random.gauss(0, g_posJitter))

                if ((x_rand <= x < x_rand + width) and
                        (y_rand <= y < y_rand + height)):
                    Line_Orientation = random.gauss(patch_orientation,
                                                    g_oriJitter)
                else:
                    Line_Orientation = random.gauss(surround_orientation,
                                                    g_oriJitter)

                current_line = visual.Line(
                    win, units="deg", start=(0, 0), end=(0.0, 0.35),
                    pos=(x_pos, y_pos), ori=Line_Orientation,
                    autoLog=False
                )

                self.lines.append(current_line)

    def draw(self):
        [line.draw() for line in self.lines]


myStim = MyStim()
for frameN in range(10):
    myStim.draw()
    win.flip()

# Clear the screen
win.flip()
print x_rand, y_rand

core.quit()
```

Please do note that even with this approach, I am dropping frames on a 3-year-old laptop computer with relatively weak integrated graphics chip. But I suspect a modern, fast GPU would be able to handle this amount of visual objects just fine. In the worst case, you could pre-create a large set of stimuli, save them as a bitmap file via `win.saveMovieFrames()`, and present them as a pre-loaded `SimpleImageStim` during your actual study.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help - I did not even know about class until I read your post. You have helped make this really understandable for me, so thanks again.

Comment: One could have achieved a similar behavior using e.g. ordinary functions and lists *outside* a class; but I believe in the particular setting we're dealing with, classes are the superior and cleaner approach, as the class *encapsulates* data (the lines to be drawn) and respective functions to deal with these data (the `draw()` method) in a single place.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you use 
`def draw(self):
        [line.draw() for line in self.lines]` ?
Is it not usually like `for x in y` `x.draw()`

Thanks again

Comment: This so-called list comprehension is, in this scenario, just syntactic sugar and more compact than an ordinary  for loop. It's simply a matter of taste.